# How to put and align figures in multicols environment

Tags: latex, figure, pdflatex, caption, multicol

I write an article, which is divided into two columns separated by a line. I use `multicol` package. I want to insert figures and align them to the top or to the down of the page in `multicols` environment. Figures can be inserted by the use of `minipage` environment by i don't know how to align them up or down. `figure` environment does not work in `multicols` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}

\geometry{margin=0.75in}

\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \lipsum[1-3]

        \vfill

        \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{beta_glucan.png}
            \captionof{figure}{Figure caption}
        \end{minipage}

        \lipsum[1-3]
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Any help will be appreciated cause I have been loosing time at it since friday.

Comment: Is using `multicols` a must or would any two column article do?

Comment: It doesn't have to be `multicols`

Answer (score 0):

Non-`multicols` solution:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
%\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\geometry{margin=0.75in}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}
%    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \lipsum[1-3]

        \begin{figure}[tb]
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
            \caption{Figure caption}
        \end{figure}

        \lipsum[1-3]
%    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```